# Disabling a button after a click event

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have this piece of HTML code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div ng-init="controller.onInit()" style="divContainer">
    <div class="divLoading" style="vertical-align:middle" ng-show="controller.noOfLoadingInProgress > 0">
      <span class="text">  Loading ...</span> <img src="../../Styles/Images/loading.gif" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <h1>
        Test</h1>
    <div ui-view="wizardContent">
    </div>
    <!--<div class="clear">
    </div>-->
    <div>
        <a class="buttonprev" id="btnPrevious" href="#" ng-show="controller.wizard.wizardIndex > 1"
            ng-click="controller.wizard.previous()"><span>Previous </span></a>
            <a class="buttonCancel"
                id="btnCancel" href="#" ng-click="controller.wizard.cancel()"><span>Cancel </span>
            </a>
            <a class="buttonnext" id="btnNext" ng-disabled="controller.wizard.isNextInProgress"
                href="#" ng-show="controller.termsAndCondition.isTermAndConditionAccepted  && (controller.wizard.wizardIndex < controller.wizard.wizardItems.length-1)"
                ng-click="controller.wizard.next()"><span>Next</span> </a>
            <a class="buttonnext" id="btnFinish" href="#" ng-show="controller.termsAndCondition.isTermAndConditionAccepted && (controller.wizard.wizardIndex == controller.wizard.wizardItems.length-1)"
                    ng-click="controller.wizard.finish()" ng-disabled ="controller.wizard.isFinished == 1"><span>Finish</span> </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this piece of javascript code.

```
var WizardItem = function (manager, uiState) {
    this.manager = manager;
    this.uiState = uiState;
}

var Wizard = function ($state, onFinishCallback, wizardItems) {
    var self = this;

    self.onFinishCallback = onFinishCallback;
    self.wizardItems = wizardItems;
    self.wizardIndex = 0;
    self.isNextInProgress = false;
    self.isFinished = 0;

    self.refresh = function () {
        $state.go(wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].uiState);
    };
    self.next = function () {
        if ((self.wizardIndex < wizardItems.length - 1) && wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].manager.validate()) {
            if (wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].manager.overrideNext == null) {
                self.wizardIndex++;
                $state.go(wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].uiState);
            }
            else {
                self.isNextInProgress = true;
                wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].manager.overrideNext(onFinishCallBack);
            }
        }

        function onFinishCallBack(success) {
            self.isNextInProgress = false;
            if (success) {
                self.wizardIndex++;
                $state.go(wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].uiState);
                self.isFinished = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    self.refreshWizardFrom = function (newWizardItems) {
        self.wizardItems.splice(0);
        for (var c = 0; c < newWizardItems.length; c++) {
            self.wizardItems.push(newWizardItems[c]);
        }
    }

    self.previous = function () {
        if (self.wizardIndex > 1) {
            self.wizardIndex--;
            console.log($state.go(wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].uiState));
            $state.go(wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].uiState);
        }
    };
    self.cancel = function () {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel!')) {
            $state.go('Home');
        }
    };
    self.finish = function () {
        self.isFinished = 1;
        if ((self.wizardIndex == wizardItems.length - 1) && wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].manager.validate()) {
            //Ajmal Bug 410 - Variable flag isFinished set to 1 and being called on finish button click to disable it
            self.isFinished = 1;
            self.onFinishCallback();
            self.isFinished = 1;
            // alert('finish');
        }
    };

    self.validateCurrentWizardItem = function () {
        return wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].manager.validate();
    };

    self.initAllWizardItems = function () {
        for (var c = 0; c < wizardItems.length; c++) {
            wizardItems[c].manager.onInit();
        }
    }

    self.registerValidations = function () {
        for (var c = 0; c < wizardItems.length; c++) {
            wizardItems[c].manager.registerValidations();
        }
    };

};
```

I would like to disable the finish button after clicking it once.
I've tried something like that, but it still doesn't work
in the javascript file, use a flag

`self.isFinished = 0;`

then set it to 1 in the finish function

`self.isFinished = 1`

then use ng-disabled in the html part of the code

`ng-disabled = "controller.wizard.isFinished == 1"`

Can someone figure out where may be the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Please use ng-disabled property on button instead of anchor tag as there is no disabled attribute for hyperlinks. May be it helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try do `self.wizadr.isFinished = 1;` instead of `self.isFinished = 1;`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, tried it but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable  tag. Use ng-disabled on button. Also add ng-app directive on body

Comment: The other ng directives, which are just above, used in the same context, are working as planned.

Comment: There is no disabled attribute for <a> tag , ref : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a also regarding subject - where is **ng-app** tag? I see that you are using ui-router did you specified controller and controllerAs property?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, disabling a tag did not make any sense, hence I decided to remove all the links from all the  tags with this function.

In the self.finish function, added a call to a function (in bold )

```
 self.finish = function () {
        if ((self.wizardIndex == wizardItems.length - 1) && wizardItems[self.wizardIndex].manager.validate()) {
            self.onFinishCallback();

            ConvertAnchorToSpan();
            // alert('finish');
        }
    };
```

**Outside of the Wizard, used that function in the same javascript file.**

```
function ConvertAnchorToSpan() {
    var $link = $('a');
    var $span = $('<span>');
    $link.after($span.html($link.html())).remove();
}
```

It now works and prevents multiple submissions. I removed all the isFinished flags in the javascript file as well as the ng-disabled in the html.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no disable property for anchor tag so you can use custom code for that. 
I used `ng-class` in place of `ng-disabled` It will add a class to your anchor tag and in css code is written for make this class elements disable.

```
<style>
  .disabledOn {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: grey;
   }
</style>
```

HTML

```
 <a class="buttonnext" id="btnFinish" href="#" ng-show="controller.termsAndCondition.isTermAndConditionAccepted && (controller.wizard.wizardIndex == controller.wizard.wizardItems.length-1)"
                ng-click="controller.wizard.finish()" ng-class="{disabledOn : controller.wizard.isFinished == 1}"><span>Finish</span> </a>
```

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

`ng-disabled` can't be used for `a` tag. you can use this

**HTML**

```
<a ng-click="disabled()" class="btn" ng-class="{'disabled':disable}">Click Me</a>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var count=0;
  $scope.disable=false;
  $scope.disabled = function() {
  if(count>0) { return false;}else{
    alert("do someting else");
    $scope.disable=true;
    count++;
  }
}
});
```

**CSS**

```
.disabled { cursor: default; opacity: .5; }
```

You can prevent click event by using this code after a first click.

For reference click this [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/gtWvxMLkRF0sEGQUhBw8?p=preview)

Hope it will be useful for you.